# Archimesh is not displayed in the Tool shelf

Tags: add-on, archimesh-add-on

I've enabled Archimesh and just started using it. The problem is I can't find it among the tools in the `Tool shelf`. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In toolshelf -> create -> Archimesh -> Room tools

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm looking for the `Room tools` and other settings: https://youtu.be/p5q_P8WQegQ?t=1124

Comment: Find the new answer is edited

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same after built the house that I couldn't find the "archimesh" tool in the left shelf beacuse I left the project but I didn't save the the "User Preferece" windows when I accept the add on for the first time[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I had the same problem doing that tutorial. I found that panel under Create -> Archimesh.

Cheers :)

Comment: What does this answer add that the already accepted answer doesn't have?