# Archimesh, properties?

Tags: modeling, archimesh-add-on

[image]In relation blender 2.79 and the archimesh tool shelf missing, which was answered in [Archimesh is not displayed in the Tool shelf](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93423/archimesh-is-not-displayed-in-the-tool-shelf)

The properties panel is disabled. For example when i add a column i cannot change top or base or add an arch. What do i need to do to enable it?

I posted a follow up there, apologies for that.

Comment: You mean you want to adjust the parameters of the wall for example

Comment: Provide image what you mean

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to attach an image. In the meantime, add a column, you will find the properties (in the T panel) grayed out... That's for Blender 2.79, in 2.78 its fine.

Comment: Press edit -> Press ctrl+G (or click the image icon) browse the image -> click on add picture and after loading the image dont forget to save edit at the bottom

Comment: And oh, if it makes any difference, i am using linux.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/what-is-causing-disabled-options-when-adding-a-mesh-curve-object-to-the-scene

Answer (score 0):

Go to User preferences -> Editing-> (check mark on) undo

Do not forget to save user setting below

[image]

Comment: No, that's not what i mean.

Comment: @agor check the new answer edited

Comment: Wow! I never thought of that, a million thanks!